# #states on exposed filter form

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have a #states on the exposed filter form as follow:

```
If field_a == 'b' then field_b show, field_c hidden;

else if field_a == 'c' then field_c show, field_b hidden;
```

All fields here are Select list.

The states is working fine, problem is the value of the hidden filter is affecting the view result, which i dont want.

Questions:

1) How to change the hidden field value back to default(to -Any- in Select List)? JQuery maybe?

2) How to avoid the hidden filter affecting the view result and to remove the filter (?...&field_b=xxx) in the query string?

updates: working code for states.

```
 $field_state = array( 'visible' => array(':input[name="field_a"]' 
 => array( array('value' => 'a') )),       );

 $form['field_a']['#states']   = $field_state
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried something to achieve this? Please share your code and whatever issue you have found.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola, I have tried the hook_views_pre_view to unset the filter, but the query string still unchanged. hook_form_alter does not help much also.

Comment: you  should update your question with your code and you should ask only question.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola, i dont have any working code for my question. The questions are related. Do you have the answer for my questions?

Comment: If you do not have any working code, then how you manage the `#states` functionality as you mentioned that _The states is working fine_. Sorry, we can't answer to your question if we do not have enough information about your functionality.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola, If you understand the question clearly, it's not about how to make the states work. States code has been updated. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have custom solutions in place, but a try for [views_dependent_filters](https://drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) can be worth, this might be hint as well for your custom solution.

views_dependent_filters module:

> Allows the presence of exposed filters on a view to be controlled by
>   values in another exposed filter. Dependent filters are hidden when
>   not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed
>   form is submitted.
>
> The module is compatible with both the Views basic and the Better
>   Exposed Filters form plugins.